# spring data jpa findAll() not working properly

Tags: spring, spring-data

I am having below classes

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "USR_E_GROUPS")
public class GroupEntity {
    @Id
    @Column(name = "UIDUSERGROUP")
    @GenericGenerator(name = "generator", strategy = "uuid2")
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "generator")
    private String id;
  .........
   @OneToMany(mappedBy = "group", cascade = CascadeType.PERSIST)
   private List<UserGroupEntity> users;
```

same is for `UserGroupEntity`
now if I use `groupRepoository.findAll()`
It's is firing select query for every Group and inside different select query for UserGroupEntity. so it's taking too much time.
I want to make it to fire select with join so it will be a single query.

Comment: Seems as if it does work properly, but you just want it to behave differently. JOIN FETCH and not lazy loading...

Answer (score 1):

This is probably an [`n + 1`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/97197/what-is-n1-select-query-issue) issue.

From the [`docs`](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/reference/en-US/html/performance.html#performance-fetching-lazy)

> By default, Hibernate3 uses lazy select fetching for collections and
>   lazy proxy fetching for single-valued associations. These defaults
>   make sense for most associations in the majority of applications.

By default the children are fetched lazily.  Use [`JOIN FETCH`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch20.html#performance-fetching) to get the result in a single query.

In your `GroupRepoository`

```
@Query("SELECT g FROM GroupEntity g JOIN FETCH g.users gu")
List<GroupEntity> findAllEager();
```